# Caracteres especiais no retorno do método Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net

Boa tarde caros,
Tenho um projeto em ASP.NET WebForm que lê o post do formulário através do método Request.Form.
Jogo esse método em uma string mas vem cheio de caracteres espaciais.s
Trecho do código --

```
        string[] ctrl = Request.Form.ToString().Split('&');

        foreach (string item in ctrl)
        {
            if (item.ToString().Contains("DropDownList="))
            {
                string[] control = item.ToString().Split('=');
                if (control[0].ToString() != "andaresDropDownList" && control[0].ToString() != "periodoDropDownList")
                {
```

-- 
A primeira linha é que faz o retorno do método mas veja o resultado no anexo,
[image: Retorno chamada método para variável string[]]

Por exemplo a a frase retornada "sem manchas" retorna "sem+manchas"
Outro exemplo. Armários retorna Arm%c3%a1rios

Podem me ajudar?

Grato e aguardo.

Bom resto de dia.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não são caracteres especiais, o seu texto está vindo `UrlEncoded` basta utilizar o decode para exibir da forma como deseja. Você pode usar o `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`.

Comment: Bom dia, Consegui sim através de sua orientação.

Comment: Boa tarde,Na verdade gostaria sim de fazer isto e encerra este assunto mas não localizei onde fazer isto no site.